# Generating field names in JOOQ

Tags: jooq, data-generation

I'm trying to generate a JOOQ model from database. For a record `FooRecord`, and a field `time_stamp`, **I'd like the resulting setters and getters to be `getTime_stamp` and `setTime_stamp`**. [XY question disclaimer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): this is for JDBI mapping. I'm not using JOOQ conventionally, just for POJO generation.

This is a snippet of my `library.xml`:

```xml
    <strategy>
      <matchers>
        <fields>
          <field>
            <expression>^(.*)$</expression>
            <fieldIdentifier>
              <transform>AS_IS</transform>
            </fieldIdentifier>
            <fieldSetter>
              <transform>UPPER_FIRST_LETTER</transform>
              <expression>set$0</expression>
            </fieldSetter>
            <fieldGetter>
              <transform>UPPER_FIRST_LETTER</transform>
              <expression>get$0</expression>
            </fieldGetter>
          </field>
        </fields>
      </matchers>
    </strategy>
```

This generates `Gettime_stamp()` and `Settime_stamp(Timestamp)`.

I tried using their default AS_IS generator and this generates `time_stamp()`/`time_stamp(Timestamp)`, and also `gettime_stamp()`/`settime_stamp(Timestamp)`

The problem is that the `transform` is applied after the `expression` clause and not vice-versa.

Is there a way to generate the setters/getters as I want them using the xml settings, and without having to implement my own Generator class in Java?

Comment: You'll have to implement that programmatically

Comment: Ok, thanks for the blazing fast reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lukas Eder said, I implemented the GeneratorStrategy based off of the example shown in the [docs](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/):

```java
public class AsInDatabaseStrategy extends DefaultGeneratorStrategy {

  public String capitalize(String input) {
    return input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
  }

  @Override
  public String getJavaSetterName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
    return "set" + capitalize(definition.getOutputName());
  }

  @Override
  public String getJavaGetterName(Definition definition, Mode mode) {
    return "get" + capitalize(definition.getOutputName());
  }

}
```

I added the implementation class and repackaged the JAR and ran it, and now the setters and getters were generated the way I wanted them. Thanks again.